# How to install the any downloaded software packages via teminal

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation

As a new Ubuntu user I installed the OS by downloading the software via terminal commands without problems. Now I would like to install additional software packages. While trying to install downloaded packages via terminal I get errors. Please help me to install the downloaded Debian packages with terminal commands and please address possible repository dependencies.

The reason for not installing software from online repositories is that this produces reasonable internet traffic that cost me a lot. Therefore it would be good to find a way to install software packages without the need to download them each time.

Comment: because you are new i would recommend you to never skip using `sudo apt-get update` command before installing any application specially after adding new repository, because this is the major cause of error for new users

Answer (score 0):

To install deb packages via terminal, run:

```
sudo dpkg -i [DEB_PACKAGE]
```

You can read all about Repositories @

- [Repositories/Ubuntu - Community Help Wiki](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Fcommunity%2FRepositories%2FUbuntu&ei=0EydVfWnCcfNsAXCxqrYBQ&usg=AFQjCNG4GdiWJnvIRaSjq-b6aOHN0e9eCg&sig2=sZrat4wMOrDcsTmrab1wwQ)
- [Your Guide To Ubuntu Repositories and Package Management](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CGsQFjAK&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.makeuseof.com%2Ftag%2Frepositories-package-management-ubuntu%2F&ei=0EydVfWnCcfNsAXCxqrYBQ&usg=AFQjCNHn1pTmB-Bnnw16T_hzCVvW5IFQ9w&sig2=rcW3nhiwqiwZrg3wc10pTQ)

Answer (score 0):

For .rpm files:

```
sudo alien -d [name of rpm] # it will create deb file
sudo dpkg -i [name of deb]
```

For .deb files:

```
sudo dpkg -i [name of deb]
```